# Embed PPT in message body of email

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010

Is there anyway that i can embed PPT in message body of email & not send as an attachment

Comment: You want it COMPLETELY inside outlook or other services may help.

Comment: it would be good if COMPLETELY inside outlook, Is there any services that i can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Google Docs](http://docs.google.com/) or [SlideBoom](http://www.slideboom.com/) to do the same, either upload it to Google Docs and use embed option to get the HTML code and Insert into the Email (Guides to insert HTML in outlook email below) or If you can host the PPT file somewhere on the internet (Direct link on a NON-secure connection) then You can use the Docs Presentation viewer to do the same with this code 
`<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=<ppt file URL here>&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>`.

How to insert HTML into outlook Email:
[How-to 1](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/sending-html-emails-with-outlook-2010/90fa8f5e-1153-4cdf-a93f-a1031d7cd62b)
[How-to 2](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/26)

You may also like to read this:
[Embed powerpoint web html or flash](http://www.free-power-point-templates.com/articles/embed-powerpoint-web-html-or-flash/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really an easy way, but, the way I would do this is by clicking `File` > `Save and send` > `Create Handouts`.

This should create a picture of each slide in Microsoft Word.

I would then cut/copy and paste each picture to the body of the email.

Comment: thanks for answer, but i want that it should display as ppt for recipient rather than pictures

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old article but you could also try this add-in for PowerPoint that does a "smart" export of slides to an Outlook Email using custom layout and style formatting:

Feature article : http://youpresent.co.uk/exporting-powerpoint-slides-outlook-email/

Add-In : http://youpresent.co.uk/office-add-ins/g-tools/

Disclaimer : the add-in (which has a free trial) is published by the company I work for.

**Update 01JUL2015**

Further to the add-in solution above, it is possible to manually embed a PowerPoint slide within the body of an email so that it's editable when double clicking the object. Note that non-Outlook recipients are unlikely to be able to view or edit the embedded slide.

To embed a slide:

1. Open **PowerPoint**
2. Select the **Slide** in the left hand side thumbnail view
3. Copy it to your clipboard using **Ctrl+V**
4. Open **Outlook**
5. Create a new email
6. Put the cursor in the body of the email
7. In the Outlook ribbon, click the **Message** tab
8. In the **Clipboard** group, click the **Paste** drop-down menu (bottom half of the button) and select Paste Special. You can also use the shortcut **Ctrl+Alt+V**
9. In the dialog that opens, click **Microsoft PowerPoint Slide Object**
10. Click **OK**

The slide will now appear within the email body in view mode and you either resize it or double-click it to switch to edit mode (you may have to accept a security message that begins with "Some objects contain viruses that can be harmful to your computer."). When done, just click anywhere else in the email to exit edit mode.

If there is interest, we may add this feature to our G-Tools add-in above.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem and discovered that if I open the document in Adobe Reader and click on edit then snapshot I can define an area (I selected a whole page) to be copied.  Then I simply went to the open email and clicked on the message area and pasted the image using crt v. The other paste methods worked as well.